# How to select the value of a drop down

Tags: select, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to select and option in a drop down using `casperJS`. My html

```
<select data-role="none" id="selectStatus">

<option value="SINGLE">Single</option>
<option value="MARRIED_FILING_JOINTLY">Married Filing Jointly</option>
<option value="MARRIED_FILING_SINGLY">Married Filing Separately</option>
<option value="HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD">Head of Household</option></select>
```

and my JS is

```
var status = 2; // Single , Married Filing Jointly , Married Filing Separately , Head of Household
//trying different ideas here... 
if(status == 1){
            status = 'SINGLE';
        }else if(status == 2){
            status = 'HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD';   
        }else if(taxFilingStatus == 3){
            status = 'MARRIED_FILING_JOINTLY';  
        }else if(taxFilingStatus == 4){
            status = 'MARRIED_FILING_SINGLY';   
        }

this.evaluate(function () {
        $('#selectStatus').val(status).change();
    });
    this.echo(status);
    this.capture(CapturePath('StatusSelected.png'));
```

I don't get the status selected when passed as a variable but when I pass the variable like this

```
$('#selectStatus').val('SINGLE').change();
```

any hint what is the problem here? Are there any limitation in passing strings?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass `status` variable inside of `page.evaluate`, so it is undefined in the browser context, hence it doesn't work.

The correct way to do pass it:

```
this.evaluate(function (status) {
    $('#selectStatus').val(status).change();
}, status);
```